# How to disable delete once the thread has been started in advanced forum module in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

If there are no comments on the current topic then user can delete the post.

If there are one or more comments on the forum-topic then user will not be able to edit or delete forum-topic.

Which module should i use or which hook needs to be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [hook_node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7)() where $op == 'delete'.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7